# How to change citation language in Microsoft Word for Mac 2015 (15.17.1)?

Tags: ms-office, language

When I add a source without a date to my Microsoft Word document in Microsoft Word 2015 (15.17.1) on OS X 10.11.2 and insert a citation, the inserted field states `(Author, kein Datum)` in German (`kein Datum` translates to `no date`). But I'm writing this document in English language and want the inserted field to actually state `no date` in English.

In the bottom line, Word states that the document language is `English (UK)` and my system language (`System Preferences > Language & Region`) is also English.

How can I change the language of the inserted field containing the citation?

Comment: Workaround would be to right-click the citation `Edit This Citation... > Suppress: Year`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rather inconvenient solution to this problem, but this seems to be the only currently available solution due to the lack of Mac OSX support of Microsoft Word features.

After inserting the reference in German (or whatever) language, you can right-click it and choose `Toggle Field Codes...`. Then you will see the code of the inserted field. For German citations this is something like `{CITATION ABC15 \l 1031}` where `ABC15` is the unique name of the source and `\l 1031` refers to the language of the inserted field. `1031` is in fact `German (Germany)` according to [Locale identification numbers for language-specific files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Locale-identification-numbers-for-language-specific-files-45393eeb-aed8-409f-9783-ca7f2a380aee?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Knowing the unique source name, you can insert a field on your own from `Insert > Field... > Citation` and in the box below enter `CITATION ABC15 \l 1033` where `1033` now stands for `English (US)`. Then the citation will be inserted in English (US) language. More information on the citation field can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-Citation-field-18b0c6a3-c0e6-4f76-a541-478f389b287d).

Looking at Microsoft Word 2015 **for Windows**, there you have the ability to change the language of every single source in the *Edit Source* dialog and also to gather its unique name from the *Edit Source* dialog.

Comment: In Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16, you can choose the language of each source in `Citation Source Manager -> Edit -> Language`.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach (if you only have a few citations to change & you won't be modifying your text anymore) is to change the citation into a "Static text" and manually rewriting the citation.

1. What you do is you find the citation that you wish to edit.
2. Click it once so that the the "grey background" appears behind the text and on the right side of the "grey background" a blue arrow also appears.
3. Click the arrow and a drop down list should appear.
4. Click "Convert Citations to Static Text"

Now the Citation is free to be manually edited.